# How to filter the map only equal to the items in the array

Tags: javascript, node.js

hello guys i have a map like this

```
Map {
'708335088638754946' => 38772,
'712747381346795670' => 12051,
'712747409108762694' => 12792 
}
```

and i have a array like

```
let array = ["712747381346795670", "708335088638754946"]
```

How can I filter the map only equal to the items in the array

Comment: whats the desired output?

Comment: i want convert key and values to like this ```{channel: key, time: value}```

Answer (score 1):

You could just iterate over all entries and only add matching entries to the result:

```
const result = new Map();
const array = ["712747381346795670", "708335088638754946"];
for( const [ key, value ] of input.entries() ) {
  if( array.includes( key ) ) {
    result.set( key, value );
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah i think its a best solution, is that okey if i push array just value in your code

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. The code here basically filters your map by the keys given in the array. If you want to do something else, you have to adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
const map = new Map([["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]);
const array = ["a", "c"];
console.log(map);
for (let [prop, value] of map) {
  if (array.includes(prop)) {
    // collect matched items here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `Object.entries` along with the function `Array.prototype.map` as follow:

```js
let data = {'708335088638754946': 38772,'712747381346795670': 12051,'712747409108762694': 12792 };
let array = ["712747381346795670", "708335088638754946"];
let result = Object.entries(data)
      .filter(([k]) => array.includes(k))
      .map(([key,value]) => ({[key]: value}));
      
console.log(result);
```

Another approach could be the function `Array.prototype.reduce`

```js
let data = {'708335088638754946': 38772,'712747381346795670': 12051,'712747409108762694': 12792 };
let array = ["712747381346795670", "708335088638754946"];
let result = Object.entries(data)
      .reduce((a, [k, v]) => a.concat(array.includes(k) ? {[k]: v} : []), []);
      
console.log(result);
```

Using the object `Map`

```js
let data = new Map([['708335088638754946', 38772],['712747381346795670', 12051], ['712747409108762694', 12792]]);
let array = ["712747381346795670", "708335088638754946"];

let result = new Map(Array.from(data.keys())
      .reduce((a, k) => a.concat(array.includes(k) ? [[k, data.get(k)]] : []), []));

console.log(result.has("712747409108762694"));
console.log(result.has("708335088638754946"));
console.log(result.has("712747381346795670"));
```

Comment: can u add how to convert map to object like that u sent

Answer (score 1):

```
const oldMap = new Map([["a", "1"], ["b", "2"], ["c", "3"]]);
const array = ["a", "c"];
const newMap = new Map(array.map(key => [key, oldMap.get(key)]));

// newMap is the same as oldMap but only with keys from array
```

or

```
const oldMap = new Map([["a", "1"], ["b", "2"], ["c", "3"]]);
const array = ["a", "c"];
const newMap = new Map([...oldMap.entries()].filter(entry => array.includes(entry[0])))

// newMap is the same as oldMap but only with keys from array
```